# Visual Studio Online - Hosted Build Agent - Why is obj\Debug not created and/or not accessible?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, azure-devops

One of our customers uses Visual Studio Online ( http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx ) which is based on capabilities of Team Foundation Server (TFS)

We were researching how to do automated Builds and automated Unit Tests using the Visual Studio Online hosted build agent.

We are trying to build one of our Web Applications on it.
 **Note: The Web Applications will build properly and run properly on our local development computers using Visual STudio 2012**

Sadly, we get the following errors pertaining to obj\Debug

```
$/BlahBlah Master Framework/BlahBlahUIFrameworkForBuildTst/BlahBlah.sln - 4     error(s), 21 warning(s), View Log File
 C:\a\src\BlahBlahUIFrameworkForBuildTst\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.13    \tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets (79): The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task     failed unexpectedly.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the     path 'C:\a\src\BlahBlahUIFrameworkForBuildTst\BlahBlah\obj\Debug\BlahBlah.csproj.App.config' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess     access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,     FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean     bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess     access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath,     Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess     access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
    at System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings.CreateWriter(String outputFileName)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(String fileName, SaveOptions options)
   at Roxel.BuildTasks.EnsureBindingRedirects.Execute()
   at     Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecution    Host.Execute()
   at          Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()
 CSC: Source file 'obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-    8F5ADCB23D92.cs' could not be found
CSC: Source file 'obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-    f7221da3dda1.cs' could not be found
 CSC: Source file 'obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-    8E70B10BC5D3.cs' could not be found
```

Basically, analyzing the errors above, it states that the Build process is Unauthorized to Access the obj\Debug

However, later on it also states that some files in the obj\Debug\ could Not be found.  For Example, here is one of the errors:

```
 CSC: Source file 'obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs' could not be found
```

I know it's probably Poor practice, but I tried to commit the obj\Debug\ folder(s) from my local development computer, however, it still threw the aforementioned errors.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that the obj\Debug\ folder(s) should just get created by the build process itself, and therefore should Never be committed to the Visual Studio Online Repository( or even any kind of code repository).

In Any Case, let me explain how my Visual Studio Online's Hosted Build Agent's Build Definition settings are:

For Source Settings, I've only ensured that Working Folders involve my Web Application's "Source Control Folder" corresponds to the "Build Agent Folder" with the same name.  The "Source Control Folder" and the "Build Agent Folder" have the same name.

For Build Defaults, the "Build Controller" is specified as "Hosted Build Controller"
 and the staging location is set as "Copy Build Output to Server"

For "Private Drop Location", the "Solution Specific Build Outputs" is set to False which means that all build outputs will be in the same folder.

Do I have to change configuration in my Visual Studio Online's Hosted Build Agent's Build Definition settings so that the obj\Debug is created and/or made accessible?  If yes, what configuration change should I make?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

The "obj" folder is used to store temporary object files and other files used to create the final binary. You should never reference a file in there.

Comment: Thx. I removed both "obj" and "bin" folders from the Visual Studio Online Code Respository.  However, the build still fails, and throws errors like the following:  CSC: Source file 'obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs' could not be found                                                                                                            In the Build Definition, the Source Control Folder is the root of the Web Application and the corresponding Build Agent Folder is also the root of the Web Application.  Could you please give me some more suggestions?

Comment: Is this configured as a web site or web app? Is there a single precompiled binary in the resulting bin folder?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b214b218-e3d8-463b-b627-a814507a6ac8/visual-studio-online-hosted-build-agent-why-is-objdebug-not-created-andor-not-accessible?forum=TFService#f4486be4-dc1a-4b6c-825c-01f4da84880f     @renevo suggestion to check the Solution file (.sln) file was accurate.  Therefore, I also went on to check the csproj files within the solution.